# SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE...) in Exposed

Tags: kotlin-exposed

Is it possible to do something like this in Exposed to check the existence of a row?
`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE...)`

Answer (score 0):

There is `exists` function in Exposed:

```
FooTable.select { 
   exists(BarTable.select { BarTable.id eq FooTable.id })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response (I really apreciate your work with Exposed by the way).

I was already aware of this function. But I am trying to return a boolean representing the existance of a single or multiple rows.

In SQL we can `SELECT`the `Exists` expression directly so that it return its boolean value.

Your exemple would map to something like :

`SELECT * FROM FooTable WHERE EXISTS(...)`

which returns elements from FooTable meeting the Exists condition. 

I am looking for something like this:

`SELECT EXISTS(...)`

which returns the result of the Exists statement directly.

Comment: Try to store your expression into variable like :

    `val extistsOp = exists(BarTable.select { BarTable.id eq FooTable.id })
    FooTable.slice(existsOp).select{ ... }`

Comment: Tried it, but I don't get a boolean when the row does not exist. My initial solution was to use `FooTable.slice(intLiteral(1)).select { ... }.count() > 0`. I think I'll stick with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by calling QueryBuilder, but I wish I could use more DSL descriptions.

```kotlin
val result: Int = transaction {
    addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)

    val qb = QueryBuilder(false).append("SELECT ").append(
        exists(FooTable.select { FooTable.id eq 111 })
    )

    TransactionManager.current().exec(qb.toString()) {
        it.next()
        it.getInt(1)
    } ?: 0
}
```